# Set Column Names to Indices in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe d with 2901 rows.

```
head(d)
index           V1           V2           V3           V4           V5           V6
1     1 0.0061810090 0.0064328712 0.0061484017 0.0061779441 0.0065441666 0.0059717158
2     2 0.0006206956 0.0006461670 0.0006193262 0.0006194541 0.0006557183 0.0006260470
3     3 0.0009515612 0.0009837086 0.0009368350 0.0009451564 0.0010080150 0.0009061030
4     4 0.0018297131 0.0019052822 0.0017963541 0.0018318636 0.0019390136 0.0017270329
5     5 0.0004890663 0.0005188195 0.0004888804 0.0004982749 0.0005183072 0.0004724337
6     6 0.0024545661 0.0025594465 0.0024123898 0.0024603748 0.0026013768 0.0023221302
```

For function and plot conveniency I had to transpose it.

```
td <- t(d)
```

Showing the last newly created 6 columns:

```
       [,2896]      [,2897]      [,2898]      [,2899]      [,2900]      [,2901]
index 2.896000e+03 2.897000e+03 2.898000e+03 2.899000e+03 2.900000e+03 2.901000e+03
V1    6.588442e-04 5.831684e-04 1.121615e-03 2.809617e-04 3.073592e-04 5.295372e-04
V2    6.900545e-04 6.069315e-04 1.171652e-03 2.924802e-04 3.166947e-04 5.650248e-04
```

How can I set the new column names as proper indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `names()` function:

```
td <- data.frame(t(d))
names(td) <- c(1:2901)
```

Notice that I `data.frame` the transpose to ensure that it remains a data frame before reassigning the names.

Comment: I mean to add column names to the newly transposed columns, i.e. add column names from 1:2901. It already shows as [,2901] I don't know how to modify that.

Comment: It returned a vector of 46416 characters (of which the first 2901 are indices, and the rest NAs)

Comment: names(td) <- c(1:2901) + 
length(names(td))
[1] 46416